# Array values return null constantly

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

```
public void doMatrix(){
    double[][] arrayA = {{a11,a12,a13,a14},{a21,a22,a23,a24},{a31,a32,a33,a34},{a41,a42,a43,a44}};      
    double[][] arrayB = {{b1},{b2},{b3},{b4}};

    RealMatrix matrixA = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(arrayA);
    RealMatrix matrixB = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(arrayB);
    RealMatrix matrixInvA = new LUDecomposition(matrixA).getSolver().getInverse();
    RealMatrix matrixAmp = matrixInvA.multiply(matrixB);
    tryit = arrayA[2][2];

    }
```

The Value of `tryit` continues to return null when placed in a text box in my android main activity. Am I accessing the array wrong?.

Comment: what are all of the local vars such as `a11,a12,etc...`?

Comment: Probably `a33` is `null` (And I guess, all of them)

Comment: a33 =  -1*Zs1*(2*angleC1*(Sv1/Cv1)*Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow(angleC1*(Sv1/Cv1), 2)));

Comment: i have checked that the values of a11 - a44 contain the correct double values. (note they are large numbers)

Comment: We can assume that you store values in a11, a12, a13... prior to declare arrays, don't you?

Comment: yes, they are stored in a method executed before

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid that you are confused.

If `arrayA` is declared to have type `double[][]` then it is impossible for `arrayA[2][2]` to be `null`.

The type of `arrayA[2][2]` is `double`, and `null` is not a member of that type.  **Not ever**.  The `null` value is *only* valid for reference types, and `double` is a primitive type, not a reference type.

Either the program is not as you are describing it, or *something else* is causing a different value to be placed into the text box.

---

(Now if `arrayA` was declared to be a `Double[][]`, it would be a different matter.)

Comment: Correct. Primitive types cannot be `null`.

Comment: Agreed. If `a33` was `null` then the array initialization of `arrayA` would throw `NullPointerException` when unboxing `a33`

Comment: @cyon, `double` type cannot simply aquire `null` value.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I know, but we do not see the declaration of `a33`. For all we know it could be a `Double`.

Comment: @cyon - what XtremeBiker is saying (correctly) is that the declaration and/or value of `a33` are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

the code will work fine unless you have initialised all the variables. tryit maybe returning null as it is not initialised with a value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in the syntax for accessing the array. arrayA[2][2] will return the value of the variable a33.You are getting null because probably the value of the variable a33 is null.

Comment: Okay, i will rework through my code checking all previous syntax again, thankyou :)